# Sensitive info stored as environment variables in Cloud Run vs Compute Engine

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I use a Compute Engine(CE) instance to run a PostgreSQL database server for my Cloud Run deployed RESTful api service.

I created the CE instance first. When I setup the instance, I injected the database password as an environment variable. There was no warning mentioning not to do this.

Later when I setup the Cloud Run service, under the environment variable section, there was a clear warning NOT TO INJECT SENSITIVE INFO via environment variables and suggested to use Secret Manager instead.

Does this imply that it's secure to inject sensitive info via environment variables on dedicated CE instances? Or should I always use a tool like Secret Manager no matter what the service is?

Comment: Best security practices: do not store sensitive data anywhere that might be read by unauthorized people/machines; create a strategy for rotating and revoking credentials. This means environment variables are a bad idea. Use Secrets Manager, KMS, HashiCorp Vault or Cloud Storage to store your secrets. Use the Cloud Run/Compute Engine service account to authorize access to secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that Cloud Run team has implemented a warning that the CE team hasn't. There is no more or less secure products, it's a common best practice: don't store in plain text your secrets: in file, in env vars,... even in memory now, that's why confidential computing solution has been developed by Google Cloud

So, use a service that store securely your secret. Secret Manager is an easy and simple place to achieve this. You can also use a KMS key to cipher/decipher your sensitive data. But keep your secrets secret!